# Cannot AES decrypt data in C# that was enccrypted in Objective-C

Tags: c#, objective-c, encryption, interop, aes

I have an iOS app that sends encrypted data that is later decrypted in C#. I have checked that the hex key and data received is same, but I still get Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0.

my Objective-C call is

```
  +(NSData*) encryptData: (NSData*) data
               key: (NSString*) key
{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [data bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;

}
```

my keysize is 256, blocksize is 128, padding is pkcs7, IV is null, mode is CBC (default).

My C# code to decrypt is

```
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(outputBytes))
        {
            AesManaged algo = GetCryptoAlgorithm(GetRawBrokerKey());
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, algo.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    private static AesManaged GetCryptoAlgorithm()
    {
        return GetCryptoAlgorithm(null);
    }
    private static AesManaged GetCryptoAlgorithm(byte[] key)
    {
        AesManaged algorithm = new AesManaged();

        //set the mode, padding and block size
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algorithm.KeySize = 256;
        algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
        if (key != null)
        {
            algorithm.Key = key;
        }

        algorithm.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        return algorithm;
    }
```

I tried encryption using C# and see a different hex output using the same key.
`c# encryption - 42AC7494606333309287768F47DFB35B`

```
    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] key)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");

        byte[] encrypted;
        AesManaged algorithm = new AesManaged();

        //set the mode, padding and block size
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algorithm.KeySize = 256;
        algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
        if (key != null)
        {
            algorithm.Key = key;
        }

        algorithm.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor();

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }

                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }


        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine("c# encryption - " + hex.Replace("-", ""));

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
        return encrypted;

    }
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong? I seem to be following all the online advice around defaults for mode and IV, I think.

Comment: Hex dump the arguments (key and data) in both Objective-C and C++ just prior to the encryption/decryption calls and you should find the problem. There may be a key problem, if it is a string. The other obvious difference is passing a pointer for the data vs a stream. There is no obvious error in the calling.

Comment: My hex values in c# are encrypted payload hex - DB1FB055E7961F6D2648110B1A8854CA
key hex - 708B797DDB28D167CCC19F71ED2920447C743B9BFD5B878FA5CA7A0FC35659E4

Comment: my hex values in Objective-C are -- key hex = <708b797d db28d167 ccc19f71 ed292044 7c743b9b fd5b878f a5ca7a0f c35659e4>
encrypted data hex = <db1fb055 e7961f6d 2648110b 1a8854ca>

Comment: I'm sorry but I made a stupid error, the padding is on the un-encrypted data so there is probably no padding error.

Comment: How do you pass the hex key `708b797ddb28d167ccc19f71 ed2920447c743b9bfd5b878fa5ca7a0fc35659e4` to the `NSString` key parameter. Wondering because the data does not seem to be characters.

Comment: Hex value I shared is the NSData dump I got. from the debugger. I convert the key to string as follows.  `NSData *decodedKey = [NSString Base64DecodeData:brokerKey];
        NSString *decodedKeyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedKey encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`   Base64 encoded key is `cIt5fdso0WfMwZ9x7SkgRHx0O5v9W4ePpcp6D8NWWeQ`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87187/discussion-between-kanishk-panwar-msft-and-zaph).

Comment: Random data can not be converted to a unicode string, that is why Base64 encoding or hex encoding is used. There is no need for a key string other than Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

in `GetCryptoAlgorithm`, you need to pass the private key to `GetCryptoAlgorithm`.

Comment: The key does seem to be passed with the call `GetRawBrokerKey() providing the key`. in symmetric key encryption the keys is not called a "private key", just "key".